# From a webapp I can't connect to my own url

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, curl

I have what looks like a network issue.

Indeed, when I go on my webapp and I try to do the following curl command here's the answer to it:

[image: screenshot]

Whereas if I do the same command from somewhere else, I don't have this error and I can correctly log in!

Do you have any ideas where this can come from?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access your own computer via the internet.
This is called "loopback".

Some routers prevent loopback connections as a security feature.
Most consumer-grade routers don't have any prohibition against it,
it just doesn't work.

The reason it doesn't work is that the router implements request-answer
algorithms, so is not programmed to handle the case where the answer is
actually another request.
In other words, the router implements the algorithm of request-answer
rather than request-request-answer-answer.

This works from outside of your network when not in loopback.

Comment: Hey, 
It's not from my computer, it's from a webapp which is inside a proxmox. 
Does that happen too ?

Comment: The question is whether the request comes from the router's internal network and needs to go back in via the internet. Not every router supports that.