# Wireguard server is accessible on LAN but not on WAN

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, wireguard

I'm trying to set up a wireguard for a while. After struggling more that I would like to admit. It's finally working ! I can from my PC, connect to my wireguard server in local and access the website (node-red interface) hosted on the server.

For info, my local network is in `192.168.1.0/24`
And here are my configs file :

Server (**ubuntu server 21.10** on `192.168.1.100/24`)

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.50.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <something>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <something>
PresharedKey = <something>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.50.2/32
```

Client (**Ubuntu desktop 20.04.3** on `192.168.1.33` (DHCP))

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.50.2/32
PrivateKey = <Something>
[Peer]
Endpoint = 192.168.2.100:51820
AllowedIPs = 192.168.50.0/24
PublicKey = <Something>
PresharedKey = <something>
```

This config work as expected as I can access my node-red interface on port `1880` of ip `192.168.50.1`

Then, I tried to access it through internet. So I added a port forwarding rule on my router in order to route all trafic to port `51820` to my pi

Here's the rule

[image: Port forwarding rule]

The handshake won't happen.

Here's the result of the command `sudo wg`

```
peer: <The public key of the server>
preshared key: (hidden)
endpoint: <My public ip>:51820
allowed ips: 192.168.50.0/24
transfer: 0 B received, 296 B sent
```

And on the server the `sudo wg` command show nothing received or sended.

What have I tried :

- I have tried to add another test rule to redirect the traffic from port 1880 onto my pi in order to see if I was messing with my ips but then I could access my interface from my public IP
- I have disabled (temporarly) my `ufw` firewall on both my client and my server in order to see if that was blocking
- I specifed only upd on the port redirection rule

Nothing will do it...
But when I got back to my local server IP, everythings works fine. So it's not my public/private/preshared key combo
The only thing that I can see from here, is that udp ports are blocked by my ISP. Is it something that can happen ?

**TLDR**:
I can access my wireguard vpn from local but can't access it through internet, my public ip is correct, my keys are correct, my server/client firewall are disabled.

I've posted it first [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1093765/wireguard-server-is-accessible-on-lan-but-not-on-wan) without knowing that serverfault was only for professional use case.

**Edit :**
I've discovered a [website](https://www.canyouseeme.org/) to check if our public address has blocked port. I'll try it when I come back home.
Apparently, it is not a common things for ISPs to block non common ports [source](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-forward-ports-if-my-ISP-blocks-all-inbound-connections).

My question is not similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1662084/from-a-webapp-i-cant-connect-to-my-own-url) as I'm not trying to access my public IP from my public IP. I've tried it with the mobile connection of my phone (different IP for sure as it's not event the same ISP) and I got the same results.

**Edit 2 :**
Well, while trying to debug, I've done a tracert command on my public ip. And I've discovered that my ip was registered in america. But I'm not in America, so I checked for the x time the config and I saw that the public ip was wrong :(. So that's a blunder on me as it's working fine now ! Anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you trying a connection like *computer-router-internet-router-computer*? Most consumer routers do not support it.

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to achieve yes. My ultimate goal would be to acces to my nas/webserver from anywhere through this vpn. But I don't understand why my router wouldn't support it, as, for the router, it's just a port redirection or am I wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From a webapp I can't connect to my own url](https://superuser.com/questions/1662084/from-a-webapp-i-cant-connect-to-my-own-url)

Comment: @harrymc Not really as I would try to connect to my wireguard VPN installed on my pi from another device on another network ( like my phone on my mobile connection). By the way I have tried it with my phone too and I have the same results : on my WiFi with the local IP as target everything works. But when I try my public IP with my mobile connection, nothing...

Comment: What's your public IP address as reported by the router? Does it differ from what online IP check websites show?

Comment: @DanielB I don't know if you saw it but I found the error. But yes, my public interface on the router show the same IP as the online what's my ip website. Thanks for the interrest !